# Cylinder transform into Cube with the same volume

Tags: volume

I want to convert a cylinder shape to a cube shape with the same volume but with $1$ height.

If a cylinder with a diameter of $2$ and length of $2$, what are the length and width of a cube when the given height is $1$ and the volume is same with the cylinder?

Can anybody explain how to get the length and width of the cube?

Thank you.

Comment: The volume of the cylinder is $\pi rh$, $r=1,h=2$. So, $V_{cylinder}=2\pi$. Note you don't get a cube, since the volumes are the same - so one side of the cube is $\sqrt{2\pi}\ne1$.

Comment: Thank you for the respond Sanath, I'm not good with math but I wanted to know what if, a clay shaped in cylinder form with diameter of 2 and the length of 2 then reshaped in rectangular cube form. With a minimum height of 1, what are the length and width of the clay when its transformed from cylinder form into a cuboid form?

Comment: Then you should ask that question, not the one you did.  As the cube root (not the square root) of $2 \pi$ is greater than $1$, the cube proposed by user22283 works well.  If you ask about a cuboid, you have one equation in three unknowns so there is not a unique answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the cube root (not the square root) of $2 \pi$ is greater than $1$, the cube proposed by user22283 works well.  If you ask about a cuboid, you have one equation in three unknowns so there is not a unique answer.